# Using model binding in my angular directive

Tags: angularjs, binding, angularjs-directive

I am beginning to learn Angular and so far I'm in love with it!

I have the following directive snippet:

```
app.directive('validation', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.after("<div name='" + attrs.ngModel + "'></div>");
        }
    };
});
```

Formulating a div like this doesn't seem to be the right approach.  I would think that I should do something more along the lines of:

```
element.after("<div name='{{attrs.ngModel}}'></div>");
```

but I can't quite figure out the right syntax.

Also, does this need to be compiled?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Overall, I'm trying to implement a pop-over type validation using ASP.Net data annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `template` or `templateUrl` to get some dynamic HTML like this.

```
app.directive('validation', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.myModel = attrs.ngModel;
        },
        template: '<div name="{{myModel}}"></div>'
    };
});
```

Note that using ngModel can be a bit more complicated than just using some other arbitrary attribute on your element. Checkout the ngModel vieo on egghead io for more info https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-using-ngmodel-in-custom-directives

Comment: How would I place the template in the div after the element?

Comment: @Scottie you could replace the original element by adding `replace:true` but I'm not sure how you would make it appear after the original element. I am sure it is possible but I would probably just put the directive on it's own element after the original one and pass in whatever value you want to validate